# issue in running epoches of deep learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am running these epochs while training the dataset of mango leaves in deep-learning model

```
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    verbose=1,
    epochs=15,
)
```

But I am facing this error, I am not able to run epochs I check that the data format is correct. I do not understand the error. I am running this in jupyter notebook. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 1
----> 1 history = model.fit(
      2     train_ds,
      3     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
      4     validation_data=val_ds,
      5     verbose=1,
      6     epochs=15,
      7 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:
```

Comment: The error message is incomplete, always add it completely.

Comment: Not complete traceback, so it is almost impossible to solve if not added completely.